# how can I change google default search country in chrome's search onmibox for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-chrome

I'm having isuses trying to change default country in google chrome's search onmibox on my iPhone. I've bought the phone in Colombia, but although I've set the region and language on the phone it keeps using google.com.co, when I want it to use google.com. It's not even using my country GPS location because I live in Buenos Aires, Argentina, not in Colombia.
How can I change this behaviour? I tried many things with no luck, and I can't set manually google search url in iOS.
Regards.
Matt.